# REST API naming conventations for logout

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

First to say that I am new to coding and I was wondering how should I name my logout route. For example for creating an user, I use this:
 `router.post("/users", async (req, res) => {}`
For login:`router.get("/users", async (req, res) => {}`. So what name do I have to use for logout, if the method is method is post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use verbs like create, get, delete in the URL. To create a user it should simply be like

```
router.post("/user", async (req, res) => {}
```

However for actions other than create, update, delete and get you can treat your resource as controller resource that has executable functions like checkout, start, stop, login etc. The URL will look like

```
router.post("/user/login", async (req, res) => {}
router.post("/user/logout", async (req, res) => {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You Can use whatever name you want for your route , just simply use naming by which you can understand whats happening,

For example

```
router.post("/user/create", async (req, res) => {}
router.post("/user/login", async (req, res) => {}
router.post("/user/logout", async (req, res) => {}
```

also you can use same name with different http method ,

```
router.post("/user" , ... ) 
router.get("/user" , ... )
router.delete("/user" , ... )
```

these all will be treated different respectively ...